# CSS - border radius and solid border curved inside

Tags: css

This style give a border with smoothed corners on the outside of the border but the insides of the corners are sqaured of, can I make them rounded as well?

```
img{
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;

border:white solid 8px;
}
```

[image]
Note the problem is only with images the suggestions submitted work only with a div.

Comment: You'll need to provide your HTML and full CSS statements. There's not enough to go on here. What does "insides of the corners" mean? Child elements?

Comment: I've added a screenshot, it's when applied to an image.

Comment: The thickness of your border was a missing piece of critical information here.

Comment: That solution is not working in safari

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use border-radius values as twice the border-size value to obtain inside-rounded corners.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 16px;
-moz-border-radius: 16px;
border-radius: 16px;

border:white solid 8px;
```

Answer (score 5):

you have to set a border-radius-value thats **higher than your border-width**. take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXLr9/).

```
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
border:black solid 8px;
```

Answer (score 2):

This technique requires that the image is wrapped in a div because — and I'm not sure why — in Safari psuedo-elements won't seem to render for `img` elements.

HTML

```
<div class="box"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/" /></div>
```

CSS

```
.box { 
    display:inline-block; /* Makes the wrapper flush with the image */
    line-height: 0; /* Stops a gap appearing underneath image */
}
.box, .box:before { 
    border: 8px solid #fff; 
    border-radius: 16px; 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1; 
}
.box:before { 
    display: block; 
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -8px; 
    left: -8px; 
    right: -8px; 
    bottom: -8px; 
    z-index: 2; 
}
```

The `:before` psuedo-element sits on top of the image with its inner curved border, essentially simulating the inner curved border on the image. It's a pretty nice workaround that achieves the curved inner border that you.

The `border-width` of the wrapper and image and `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` positions of the `:before` pseudo element needs to be half that of the border radius of the wrapper element.

http://jsfiddle.net/nvG5S/

Comment: Well [pseudo-elements](http://caniuse.com/#search=after) has good support and [border-radius](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) also has pretty good support, so yes. Have tried in chrome, safari and firefox and works in those. Sure it works in IE too but you'll need to test.

Answer (score 0):

If you decrease the thickness of the border will get the expected result, or increase the corner.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;

border:#000 solid 4px;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mHjRf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can mimik inside border with second border of child element

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background:#f0f5f9;
}
.border-outside{
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border:white solid 8px;
  background-color: white;
}
.border-inside {
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #7bada4;  
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="border-outside">
<div class="border-inside">  
content
</div>
</div>
</body>
```